# Pitfalls of calling system(3) or popen(3) with a constant string?

Tags: shell, c

Assuming for a second that you explicitly set "problematic" environment variables like `PATH`, `IFS`, and possibly some of the `LC_*` variables, how bad of an idea is it to use `popen` and `system` with a string whose value is a compile-time constant (to allow for differences between Unices and weirdness like non-POSIX `/bin/sh`'s).

For instance if I have some C code that uses a snippet like the following to perform a depth-first search of files in the current directory, is this a problem from a security/correctness standpoint?

```
FILE* fh = popen("2>/dev/null /usr/bin/find . -print0 -type f");
```

EDIT: example that forces a clean environment and doesn't include non-portable options

```
FILE* fh = popen("2>/dev/null /usr/bin/env -i /usr/bin/find . -type f");
```

Comment: For this I'd use `fts(3)` instead of shelling out to `find`. This avoids shellshock or similar bugs in the shell layer.

Comment: Is the premise that you're doing that in a setuid/setgid executable and that you don't want the calling of sh resulting in an arbitrary command injection vulnerability? Note that some shells drop their privileges when invoked in a setuid context (geteuid() != getuid()) so the code above won't work with those (assuming you expect it to be run with the euid)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My question is a bit less sophisticated than that, but that's a good reason to avoid system and popen. I wasn't thinking about how these functions worked from a privileges standpoint. I had read in some secure C (and Perl) programming guidelines to avoid `popen(3)` and `system(3)`. There were some examples with dynamically generated strings and some others involving `IFS`. I was wondering what problems remain when the string is a compile time constant and the environment is carefully scrubbed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming for a second that you explicitly set "problematic" environment variables like...

Don't do that.

It's somewhat hard to identify all the environment variables some program might care about. Somewhat easier to just give the program a clean environment with only the necessary variables set.

If you're running a simple command like that, just use one of the `exec` functions, so you don't need to care about issues regarding different shells.

If you know you're calling a standard utility, you could be pretty sure you know what it's doing, and any resource limits and such would probably strike your program too if you were to implement the function yourself.
But there are variants of `find` with non-standard extensions, like the `-print0` you used, so if you use them, you depend on a version of the external program that supports them.